# Leaflet - button in a popup should refer to onclick.location but doesn't

Tags: javascript, button, reference, leaflet, popup

I'm new in programming with leaflet and would define myself still a newbie to html, javascript, etc.
In a hobby-project I plan to collect data in a database.
In my steps to get there I wanted to reach something before.
What should happen:

- Click on a map
- A Popup will open
- There are categories to pick from [with buttons]
- After I picked a category something specific should happen (thats for later when im more expirienced)
- Just for now: an alert should open with my category and the latitude and longitute (of the onclick-function) should be visible

But right now, the alert won't open anymore with the code below. Do you have any hints for me, what function I should look into, to solve my problem? Or is it even more easier, some sort of typo even?

Thank you so much :)

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    newpopup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)        
        .setContent("<h4>Neuen Standort hinzufügen</h4> <p>Füge einen Standort hinzu z.B. dein Lieblingsrestaurant.</p>" + '<button id="Restaurant" ion-button class="button-action" onclick="btn_action_res() + e.latlng" block>Restaurant</button>'
            + '\n <button id="Spielplatz" ion-button class="button-action" onclick="btn_action_spi() + e.latlng" block>Spielplatz</button>') 
        .openOn(map);
}

function btn_action_res() {
    alert("Latitude : " + e.latlng.lat + "\nLongitude : " + e.latlng.lng);
    }

function btn_action_spi() {
    alert("Latitude : " + e.latlng.lat + "\nLongitude : " + e.latlng.lng);
    }

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
newpopup = L.popup();
function onMapClick(e) {
    var latlngStr = JSON.stringify([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]);
    newpopup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)        
        .setContent("<h4>Neuen Standort hinzufügen</h4> <p>Füge einen Standort hinzu z.B. dein Lieblingsrestaurant.</p>" + '<button id="Restaurant" ion-button class="button-action" onclick="btn_action_res(\''+latlngStr+'\')" block>Restaurant</button>'
            + '\n <button id="Spielplatz" ion-button class="button-action" onclick="btn_action_spi(\''+latlngStr+'\')" block>Spielplatz</button>') 
        .openOn(map);
}

function btn_action_res(latlngStr) {
    var latlng = L.latLng(JSON.parse(latlngStr));
    alert("Latitude : " + latlng.lat + "\nLongitude : " + latlng.lng);
    }

function btn_action_spi(latlngStr) {
    var latlng = L.latLng(JSON.parse(latlngStr));
    alert("Latitude : " + latlng.lat + "\nLongitude : " + latlng.lng);
    }

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

1. convert your latlng to a string: `var latlngStr = JSON.stringify([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]);`
2. Update your button `onclick` to: `onclick="btn_action_spi(\''+latlngStr+'\')"` and pass the latlng string
3. Read out the `latlngStr` in the function and then convert it back to L.latLng: function `var latlng = L.latLng(JSON.parse(latlngStr));`

Comment: Thank you, this works fine :D 
Now i'm trying connecting a database <3